# How to check whether an orientation of a rigid body has approached a target orientation

Tags: c#, math, rotation, orientation, quaternions

I have an IMU sensor which outputs its orientation using quaternions. I first hold it flat on a surface and retrieve the quaternion (**q_rest**). Then I start rotating it in random directions. I want to know when it reaches 90 degrees around its y axis. So I have a **q_target** which is equal to **(cos(pi/4) 0 sin(pi/4) 0)**.

At a given time **t** if the orientation of my sensor is **q_t** how can I check the correlation between **q_t** and **q_target**?

i.e. How do I tell the user who is rotating the sensor, how much more to rotate and in which direction.

*What have I already done?*

I've calculated the vector of rotation **q_target** and the vector of **q_t** wrt **q_rest**. Then I've checked the angle between these two vectors. But seems this don't work which I believe my understanding on the vector of rotation of a quaternion is wrong. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can formulate the problem as follows:

You want to apply a rotation `q_diff` to your current orientation, such that you get to `q_target`:

```
q_t * q_diff = q_target
```

Depending on whether you want `q_diff` expressed in the local or the global system, you could also use `q_diff * q_t`.

Then, obviously:

```
q_diff = q_t^(-1) * q_target
```

`q_diff` is then basically the distance to the target rotation. Use the angle component to determine how far it is and use the axis component to determine in which direction you have to rotate.

Of course, you can convert `q_diff` to any other representation, whatever is most user-friendly.